# "Stroke Effect" in After Effects does a rounded corner.

Tags: stroke, adobe-after-effects

How can i do a linear stroke, to use with the "Stroke Effect" in After Effects?

Attached you can find the actual result: (I want the start and the end of the stroke linear, not rounded)

[image: rounded-coreners]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you have selected (or selected by default) - Round Cap stroke.

You can change that in Layer dropdown menu -> contents -> Stroke -> Line cap -> set to "butt cap"

See the attached image for better understanding

[image]